# Is there a way to make a link appear as plain text on a screen reader but visibly be a link?

Tags: accessibility, wai-aria, screen-readers

We are trying to reduce redundant links being read out by screen readers on our blog posts. Currently the title of the post is a clickable link, as well as the "read more" being a clickable link. We still want the "read more" announced as a link to the screen reader users, but do not want the title of the post to be announced as a link, while still being visibly a link to non-screen reader users. Is this possible?

For other similar items with two similar links by each other we had been using  “aria-hidden=”true” AND a tabindex=”-1” but that makes the screen reader completely skip one of the links. We still want one of the links to read as plain text to the screen reader.

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy to do it:

```
<a role="presentation" tabindex="-1" href="#">Link</a>
```

However, it isn't a very good idea to do so:

- It's rather common nowadays for a blog to have both the post title as a link, as well as a link "read more" after the post intro, and it isn't at all a problem

  - Having the post title as a link allows to open very quickly a given post, given that the screen reader allows to jump from heading to heading
  - If I don't know well with the title alone if I want to read the post, maybe the intro will convince me, and at that time I will click on the "read more" link. Otherwise I have to go back to the post title to open it.
- tabindex=-1 must come along with role=presentation. Since the link isn't announced as such, when it takes the focus, I might wonder why this element can take focus and what it does if I press enter.
- Having a non-focusable link can confuse keyboard-only users who don't use a screen reader
- Changing the role of a natively non-neutral element isn't to take too lightly. You should have a very good rason to do so. All role replacements may not work well everywhere! As ARIA rules say, you should avoid using ARIA, unless you have no better solution
- Just in case, I haven't actually tested, but removing the link role probably won't make screen readers read the text continuously better than with the link, if it was your concern